# phonegap with geolocation in background in IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, background, geolocation

All,
I'm working on an application that uses geolocation services provided by phonegap (using latest version 2.2.0. I'm testing this for now only on IOS (ultimately I wanted to work at least on Android as well).
On IOS when application in foreground all works fine. When the application goes to background however the geocoding stops working and I don't get the change position event anymore.
I do have the required "App registers for location updates" under Required background modes section of my app-info plist and I've done ISO coding using this flag and my application reports the location change even when app is in background so I was wondering why this is not working on phonegap.

I'm not doing any fancy work. My code is simply a copy of what cordova code is for watchPosition.

Any pointers or help would be appreciated.

Amir

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that JavaScript in PhoneGap does not run when the app is in the background. To provide background process capability you'll need to create a plugin to manage the background process.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html

I know of an already existing plugin to do this for Android but not one for iOS.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BackgroundService

Comment: The PowerManagement plugin exists for both [Android](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/PowerManagement) and [iOS](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/PowerManagement) but needs updating for the latest version of phonegap. This will allow you to acquire a full wakelock and keep the screen on but can easily be extended to support a partial wakelock (keep CPU running phonegap app in background when screen is off)